# How to add title attribute to archive items

Tags: php, loop

How can I have the title attribute to each listed archive item, so when I hover an item, it says: view all posts in archive: ''

```
$html = wp_get_archives( array(
    'show_post_count' => false,
    'echo' => true,
) );
// Wrap the post count in a span element
$html = preg_replace( '~(&nbsp;)(\(\d++\))~', '$1&rsaquo;&#32;<span class="count">$2</span>', $html );
// Output the result
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you [look at the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L937), you will see that the `HTML` is generated by `get_archives_link`, which applies the filter [`get_archives_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L905). Applying a callback to that filter is probably the most straightforward way to add a title attribute. Unfortunately it is not one of the more friendly filters and requires you to regex the generated markup in order to do much of anything.

Let's walk through your code.

First, if you want to manipulate the code before printing it you need to set `echo` to true. As written, the links print to the screen immediately and are not captured in your `$html` variable.

Secondly, I am not sure why you are trying to wrap the count in a span when you have `show_post_count` set to `false`. I'll assume that is just debugging.

Third, the markup already has a title attribute, which makes this considerably easier. That is where the filter comes in.

```
function archive_title_attr_wpse_127698($html) {
  $pat = "|title='([^']+)'|";
  $html = preg_replace($pat,"title='View all posts in archive: $1'",$html);
  return $html;
}
add_filter('get_archives_link','archive_title_attr_wpse_127698');
```

You can define that callback in `functions.php` or in a plugin but you probably want to apply it right before the links you want to manipulate and remove it afterwards with `remove_filter('get_archives_link','archive_title_attr_wpse_127698');`... unless you want to have a global effect.

Comment: Well im still new to php so yes if you could please further assist me then that would be great

Comment: @Eric : see the edit

Comment: Thank you for your response and explanation. I've defined the callback in my functions.php , but where exactly do I call it?

Comment: The `add_filter` is what triggers it. The code above if pasted into `functions.php` will apply the changes globally, across the whole theme.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I did something wrong, but I've applied your whole function archive_title_attr_wpse_127698($html) to my functions.php , but non of the archive links get's a title attribute.

Comment: Including the `add_filter` line?

Comment: yes including the add_filter line

Comment: I tested this earlier. Something must be interring-- a plugin perhaps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12191/discussion-between-eric-and-s-ha-dum)